# FB doesn't update page post link meta data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting to fb page using PHP Curl from my website. I keep post title, description, url and other properties which need for posting. And when I change post title or image and update post from website in FB page data isn't updated. I know that we can't update post link when update fb post. Also I have problem like this when share link from website with share plugin, FB doesn't update meta data when I change it. It keeps old data.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue, is there a version to solve it ?
Here is my code for updating.

```
$page_access_token = 'my_nonexpiringtoken';
$page_id = 'my_page_id';
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
$message = $title;
$data['message'] = $message;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post_id;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($result);
if(isset($response->success) && $response->success){
    $info = json_encode(array('success' => true));
}
else{
    $info = json_encode(array('success' => false));
}
curl_close($ch);
return $info;
```

Comment: Facebook does not automatically update posts, just because you change the meta data of the link that was shared. The user/page that made the post have to refresh the share attachment via the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you're looking for?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I've found that facebook needs to update their own data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: No, I have tried it. It is just for debuging but it isn't fixed my problem. I think need to scrape automatically with code or refresh every time when sharing.